# live find in jQuery

Tags: jquery, find, live

I use the `find` method in jQuery to find a specific box on the page.

I have other buttons that create new boxes without page-refresh. These new boxes are then NOT found with `find`, which is a problem.

I use:

```
$("fieldset#"+new_item_id).find("div.images").append(img);
```

but am thinking of how to implement the `live` method also. Or should I use `on` or other? This live updating stuff is tough.

Comment: you should never use .live, it's obsolete

Comment: Oh, `on` then? Thank's I didn't know

Comment: `$("fieldset#"+new_item_id)` it's over qualified, meaning, not necessary to add `fieldset` infront of it

Comment: Actually if your selector is correct it'l find dynamically created elements

Comment: To build on what @Sergio says, have a look at this fiddle to see `find` working on dynamically created elements: http://jsfiddle.net/P7E9Q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to call a function on each event to achieve this.

```
function addImg( new_item_id, img ){
    $("fieldset#"+new_item_id).find("div.images").append(img);
}
```

For those elements already present you'd have to call this on page load. For each added element you call it again. So you'd end up with something like:

```
$(function(){
    $("fieldset[id]").each(function(){
        var img = //how ever you find this image...
        addImg($(this).attr('id'),img);
    });

    $('button').click(function(){
        //some ajax call
        $.ajax(
            // what ever options you have for url, data etc etc.
            success: function(response){ // assuming response is just the markup
                var $el = $(response);
                $('#content').append($el); // how ever you add this content - its probably NOT #content but you'll know that...
                var img = //how ever you find this image...
                addImg( $el.attr('id'), img );
            }
        );
    });
});

function addImg( new_item_id, img ){
    $("#"+new_item_id).find("div.images").append(img);
}
```

EDIT - rather than hav the function find the element just pass it in...

```
$(function(){
    $("fieldset[id]").each(function(){
        var img = //how ever you find this image...
        addImg($(this),img);
    });

    $('button').click(function(){
        //some ajax call
        $.ajax(
            // what ever options you have for url, data etc etc.
            success: function(response){ // assuming response is just the markup
                var $el = $(response);
                $('#content').append($el); // how ever you add this content - its probably NOT #content but you'll know that...
                var img = //how ever you find this image...
                addImg( $el, img );
            }
        );
    });
});

function addImg( $newEle, img ){
    $newEle.find("div.images").append(img);
}
```